# How to get date range between two columns?

Tags: mysql

How to get date range between two columns?

```
SELECT
     ccm.`date_from`
    , ccm.`date_to`
    , ccd.`rate`
FROM
    `currency_conversion_master` ccm
    , `currency_conversion_details` ccd

WHERE ccm.conv_m_id=ccd.conv_m_id AND DATE(date_from)>=DATE('2012-10-12')  AND DATE(date_to) <= DATE('2012-10-14')
```

in this way query does not filter the record when i put 2012-10-13.

I mean as

```
DATE(date_from)>=DATE('2012-10-13')  AND DATE(date_to) <= DATE('2012-10-14')
```

How do i do this?

This is the database structure with data

```
date_from   date_to
2012-10-12  2012-10-14
2012-10-15  2012-10-19
2012-10-20  2012-10-30
```

Comment: use the [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) function

Comment: and i got this answer too... WHERE ccm.conv_m_id=ccd.conv_m_id AND DATE(date_from)<=DATE('2012-10-13')  AND DATE(date_to) >= DATE('2012-10-14')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
SELECT
    ccm.`date_from`,
    ccm.`date_to`,
    ccd.`rate`
FROM
    `currency_conversion_master` ccm
INNER JOIN `currency_conversion_details` ccd 
ON ccm.conv_m_id=ccd.conv_m_id
WHERE '2012-10-12' between DATE(date_from) and DATE(date_to)
```